# Unable to delete an excel macro in macbook pro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am not able to delete a macro in excel. I am using Macbook Pro.

Error:
Cannot edit a macro on a hidden workbook. Unhide the workbook using the Unhide command.

I tried:
Several articles suggesting unhide personal workbook but not sure where it is located.

Answer (score 1):

So go to the Window menu, Unhide and Personal workbook:

[image]

And this was done on a 15" macbook pro with touchbar...

[image]